# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status from disconnected

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, vpn

i have 5 lists i import into my python file and start a thread for each of them.
then i call a function "start_connecting()" and start a browser session (with an vpn extension!). following i iterate through the list with a for loop and do someting in my try block.
however after working for a random time (20min, hours) correctly, i receive "cannot determine loading status" exceptions.
the odd thing about it is, that 3 threads might not be affected and 2 are. at another time 4 might work. not depending on the thread number!

this is my code

```
for lineNum, x in enumerate(liste, 0):
    driver.get(realUrl + str(x))
    try: 
       something...
    except:
           pass
```

below is the exception. although sometimes it might differ and say "unable to receive message from renderer".
i've searched and some said the backtrace might be an inidcator of a version problem.
however i am using the newest chrome version, as you can see in the message below, and the latest chromedriver [chrome-driver-96.0.4664.45](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/). the difference betwenn .93 and .45 can't be the problem as far as i am concerned.   and i am working on a server.
[python-selenium-version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzlGZ.png). it's both the latest. is everything to new and not compatible?!
or might the vpn extension be the problem, since i rarely got these as well unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED or ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

i would be really thankfull!!, since i've looked throgh stackovererflow and tried diiferent things and noting seemed to help!

```
Exception in thread Thread-4 (start_connecting):  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()  
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)  
  File "c:\Users\localadmin\Documents\PythonProjects\Project1\main.py", line 90, in **start_connecting  
    driver.get(realUrl + str(x))**
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 430, in get self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})  
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute  
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)  
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",  
  line 243, in check_response  
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status  
from disconnected: unable to send message to renderer  
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.93)  
Stacktrace:  

Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00C46903+2517251]
        Ordinal0 [0x00BDF8E1+2095329]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AE2848+1058888]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AD414A+999754]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AD4357+1000279]
        Ordinal0 [0x00ADF131+1044785]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AD54D9+1004761]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AD60E0+1007840]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AD572A+1005354]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AD4DDA+1002970]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AD3F8D+999309]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AD4246+1000006]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AE3E1A+1064474]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B3616D+1401197]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B264D3+1336531]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B35BBF+1399743]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B2639B+1336219]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B027A7+1189799]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B03609+1193481]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00DD5904+1577972]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00E80B97+2279047]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00CD6D09+534521]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00CD5DB9+530601]
        Ordinal0 [0x00BE4FF9+2117625]
        Ordinal0 [0x00BE98A8+2136232]
        Ordinal0 [0x00BE99E2+2136546]
        Ordinal0 [0x00BF3541+2176321]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x750B0419+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x776C72FD+237]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x776C72CD+189]
```

Comment: Chances are there is an orphaned driver process.  With multiple threads/drivers there can be issues cleanly quitting the drivers.  One thing that helps is to make sure there is a sleep(give it at least 4-5 seconds) between the time you quit one driver and launch a new one.  (This gives the browser time to cleanup... the webdriver doesn't really know when the cleanup on the browser side is done.)  That may cause a browser to launch and not be able to drop the file with the driver's sessionID.

Comment: I think this can also happen when the driver is left in nomans land... for instance, you switch the driver to a certain window handle or frame and then that window/tab/frame is closed, but the driver is never switched back to an existing handle or parent frame.